# Custom html output of form

Tags: 6, forms

I want to theme a form in drupal. I know I can add and remove things to the form using `hook_form_alter()`, change the text etc. Great!

I also want to add some custom html to the form. For example adding a div with some text between two form elements.

I want to do this on the comment form. The comment form has the ID comment_form. So I need to add it to the theme registry.

```
function mytheme_theme() {
    $items = array();
    $items['comment_form'] = array('comment_form' => array('arguments' => array('form' => NULL)));
    return $items;
}
```

So I then need to add a function to be called

```
<?php
  function mytheme_comment_form($form) {
    // stuff goes here
  }
?>
```

How do I affect the html in this function and render it on the page?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the html in your form_alter, just use `'#type' => 'markup'.`